# SSDT installer missing prerequisite: SQL Server 2016 System CLR Types

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, installation, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

I have attempted installing an update to Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools into Visual Studio 2015 Professional. Upon doing so I receive the following error message:

> Setup is missing an installation prerequisite:
> -Microsoft SQL Server 2016 System CLR Types. To continue, install SQL Server 2016 System CLR Types from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398158 and then run the Setup operation again.

The hyperlink provided by Microsoft actually takes me to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack. Nonetheless, I continue to install `ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi`. Just to be extra sure, I navigated to [Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) and installed `ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi` from the latest version of SQL Server.

When running the SQL Server Data Tools installer again I receive the same fatal error in the installer message and log file. The log file reports the error code `0x80070643`. The most helpful article I have found relating this issue is [KB976982](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/976982). I have tried running the Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool; the tool failed to resolve the problem and I am continuing to work through it.

Comment: What's the OS on your machine? Do you have the latest Windows Update installed?

Comment: It was Windows 10 at the time with latest updates installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to open my VS professional 2015 with update 3 and go to Tools-Extensions and Updates… and Updates-Product Updates and there should have an update for SSDT, click ‘Update’ button to install, it installed successfully.

If this behavior not works for you, you can go to Control Panel—Programs and Features and uninstall the Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2016 items and earlier versions then navigate to the [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all) and download ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi and ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi, then install them. After that, install the above SSDT again. Meanwhile, make sure you are login as the local admin account not a domain account to do this installation.

BTW, the error code 0x80070643 is a general error code, the root cause of this failed installation should be recorded in the log file, you can also use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: I have followed all of the steps you have suggested and had no luck so far. Log file for [SSDT](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah0PMmLPgqljblY99BUNdXk7c7E) and the log file for [SMO](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah0PMmLPgqljbVzwQsuUF-2ISkA). I have discovered that SMO is the installer that fails because of the SQLSysClrTypes dependency.

Comment: Temporarily disable any antivirus and firewall or online backup software if you have, uninstall earlier versions of the management objects and SQLCLRTypes, then download the SQLSysClrTypes.msi(x86/x64) and SharedManagementObjects.msi(x86/x64) from Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Feature Pack：https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all and run as administrator to install SQLSysClrTypes.msi firstly, after that, install the SharedManagementObjects.msi.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and above solution (**Updating SSDT**) didn't work for me. So, here is the working solution with step by step instructions:

1. **Open** [SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676)
2. Click on **Download**
3. **Select** `ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi` AND `ENU\x86\ReportViewer.msi`
4. **Click** Next (Download will Start)
5. Now **Install** both `msi` files
6. Finally, **Re-Install** SQL Server 2016

**NOTES:**

1. [SQL Server 2016 Step by Step Installation Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34582.sql-2016-step-by-step-guide-installation.aspx) for Newbies
2. Don't need to Un-Install existing installation
3. Don't need to Create New Instance in installation process, just select older instance
4. Tested on **Windows 8** with **Visual Studio 2015 update 3** on `14-August-2017`

Hope it will help someone! :)